# Does Thymeleaf have something like JSP tags?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I **don't** mean taglibs, I'm using a JSP tag to do something like this:

***ChildPage.jsp***:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<t:layout>
    <jsp:attribute name="head">
        <link href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="scripts">
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        <p>This is from the child page</p>
    </jsp:body>
</t:layout>
```

***layout.tag***:

```
<%@ tag description="Layout template" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ attribute name="head" fragment="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="scripts" fragment="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <jsp:invoke fragment="head"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <p>This is from the parent or "layout"</p>
            <jsp:doBody/>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <jsp:invoke fragment="scripts"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***When rendered***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <p>This is from the parent or "layout"</p>
            <p>This is from the child page</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This allows me to include scripts in the header section of the JSP from both the  layout and child pages. Same for the body and footer.

I've read through Thymeleaf docs/examples but maybe I'm not understanding correctly as it doesn't look like I can do what I am trying to achieve.

The reason why I have "inverted" what seems like a simple include is every page that I have includes certain scripts and a header section, but my child pages also have scripts to be imported and stylesheets to be included.

Can I achive this somehow? Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: you don't want `th:replace`? like `<head th:replace="/html/components/head :: head">`

Comment: @robertotomás I don't want to replace all the contents inside the HTML `<head>` node, I want to merge the contents.

Comment: I actually don't understand what you are doing .. I guess if your example had multiple `jsp:invoke fragments` it would be different, but in the case you provided it really isn't something you couldnt do with simple substitution.

Comment: @robertotomás I have figured it out, will post an answer shortly. Thanks though.

Comment: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinclude-and-threplace you can _definitely_ do it with `th:replace` .. glad you found your own solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Thymeleaf uses so called *Include-style layouts*. Disadvantages of this approach [explained](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html) on official site. I would advise you to use [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect). This is much more convenient dialect to create *Hierarchical-style layouts*.

By the way, in Layout Dialect all content of `<head>` tag will be merged automatically. Just take a look on [example](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect#decorators-and-fragments).

Comment: I used the Thymeleaf Layout Dialect as described. I will attach my solution to my question.